# Filtering a grid - Ext Js

Tags: search, extjs, filter, grid

I'm trying to search for a particular field based on what a user searches in a textfield. For instance:

```
items: [ 
            { xtype: 'panel', padding: 5, height: 500, width: '35%',
                    items: [
                        { xtype: 'textfield', padding: 5, region: 'west', fieldLabel: 'Criteria 1', itemId: 'criteria_1'  }, ...
```

And here's code from my view class:

```
store.filter('KBE_ID', '#criteria_1');
```

I want to return a filtered search that uses the value of my textfield. Could this be done by giving it an itemId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get your reference to the field using the `itemId`, then do the filter using `getValue()`:

```
var searchField = myPanel.down('#criteria_1');
store.filter('KBE_ID', searchField.getValue());
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'm just confused about what myPanel is a reference to.

Comment: `myPanel` is a reference to any parent panel of the search field.  Without seeing the full context of your code, I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but `x.down('#criteria_1')` will work for any `x` that is a parent of `criteria_1` in the component hierarchy.